# Script Image Loading on HTTPS

Tags: javascript, css, image, ssl, https

I have a script tag on an HTML page that references an external script URL. The HTML page and the script run on HTTPS URLs. However, the script creates an IMG tag which references an image that is on an HTTP URL. I don't have control over the script itself (it is hosted by a third party). The problem is that the browser complains about loading HTTP content on an HTTPS page.

I tried the following:

- Hiding the image using CSS display property - This still causes the image to load and the browser to complain
- Changing the SRC attribute of the image using JavaScript/JQuery - this doesn't solve the problem because the script and the image load first and then my JavaScript runs

The image itself is not necessary, I can hide it or remove it. Also, if needed, I can host the image myself on HTTPS, but I still need to change the SRC attribute BEFORE the image loads.

Any suggested workarounds?

Comment: You could use relevant path `../path/img.png` in the CSS, or use `//domain.com/path/img.png`, so that it will automatically choose whether it's over http or https.

Comment: @Pangloss the URL for the image tag is hardcoded in the script that I don't have control over, so I can't change it.

Comment: hmm... no idea on that, perhaps you should also tag it as `ssl` etc. that is not a CSS question for sure.

Comment: Can't you just ask the author to change the script? I mean if the script itself is coming over `https` than why would the author bother to let the `img` be secure?

Comment: @DavidDomain I have. This company takes a while to fix bugs. I need a quick workaround.

Comment: Without knowing what the script does it is pretty hard to tell what to do.  The best thing against mixed content is to avoid it. Can you access any of the objects, properties or methods of the script, that create the url to the img? If so you could try to change those as soon as the `DOM` is ready.